# Convert stream bytes to string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using google protocol buffers to send some data from a C++ server to a IOS app. I use this function on the IOS side to convert the stream bytes to a string:

```
-(NSString*)convertStreamBytesToString:(NSMutableData*)data
{
    int len = [data length];
    char raw[len];

    [data getBytes:raw length:len];
    NSString *protocStruct =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:raw length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return protocStruct;

}
```

My problem is that sometimes this doesn't work. I can see that I send and receive all the bytes, but when converting some of them are lost. So for example I get 83 bytes, but when printing the string I get about 20 characters. Where are the rest ? Is there a problem I don't know about this converting method ?

Comment: Have you tried `NSASCIIStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: @CaptJak: Yes, with the same results

Comment: Are they all printable characters?

Comment: You should use base64 encoding/decoding to do this. Just plain binary data may not always be valid UTF-8!

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Yes, what I get from the server its a structure with data retriveve from an xml file

Comment: @nielsbot: is there something in sdk to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString is a class for  handling Unicode strings. You cannot store arbitrary bytes in it as with a C string. (And even then you probably cannot transmit binary data in place of a character string and expect it to survive the transport)

You will need to convert your binary data to a string in a way that results in a valid text string. For example via Base64 encoding.

There are lots of iOS projects you can get to encode/decode Base64, just google it.

Here's an article about it: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Allocating C array on stack in obj-c causes error sometimes.
Try to use dynamic memory for char array:

```
char* raw = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
```

And free it afterwards:

```
free(raw);
```

Comment: Still getting the same problem

Comment: This isn't the  problem. The problem is you cannot convert raw bytes to NSString--it has to be data with a valid text encoding.